# how to deal with multiple pull requests merge

Tags: git, merge, pull-request

Suppose I'm working on feature 1 branch, pushed my code to origin/feature1 branch and put a pull request to develop branch.Another person is working on feature 2 branch, pushed his code origin/feature 2 branch and raised a pull request at same time. when approver approves my request and merges it to develop branch and when he tries to approve second pull request and merges it, does it fails? because it's out of sync with develop branch where my changes were added after his pull request?(How to deal with merge multiple pull requests simultaneously?)

Answer (score 0):

Generally in these cases, github will show you error that this pull request has conflict and cannot be merge.

So possible solution would be the ask developer of feature2 branch to take pull from origin/develop and push all the things in origin/feature2. This will help in resolving conflicts as it will sync all the things with develop.

Comment: Um, OP didn't specifically ask about Github. But while we're on the subject of Github, at what stage does it show that the request has a conflict? Does it update the pull request itself to reflect the conflict? Or does it report conflicts when the pull request is actually 'merged in'?

Comment: It shows the conflict when you raise a pull request. You can check the **'diff'** tab after creating the pull request to find in which files the conflict are present.